# MigLayout align center won't center JLabel component

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, miglayout

I am using [MigLayout](http://www.miglayout.com/) I find it flexible etc,but I am having a problem with centring stuff with it. I tried using `gapleft 50%` but it seems like the percent number needs to change on different frame sizes, because it's also depending on component's size. so if the component is centred using `gapleft 25%`, it will be on a different location if i resize the width of my frame.

I've tried using just `align center` and it doesn't nothing at all.

I've also tried `new CC().alignX("center").spanX()` and same thing:

[image: img]
<sub>(source: [gyazo.com](http://gyazo.com/8b562b6dd319d0af1d85cba930af0328.png))</sub>

It's sticks to left, however it does work when I use gapleft, why?

```
    super.setLayout(new MigLayout());
    this.loginPane = new LoginPanel();

    BufferedImage logo = ImageIO.read(new File("assets/logo.png"));
    JLabel logoLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(logo));

    super.add(logoLabel, new CC().alignX("center").spanX());
```

Comment: Try using JLabel#setHorizontalAlignment and apply JLabel#CENTER

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> *It's sticks to left, however it does work when I use gapleft, why?*

Based on this single line:

```
super.setLayout(new MigLayout()); // why super? Did you override setLayout() method?
```

By default [MigLayout](http://www.miglayout.com/) rows doesn't fill all available width but only the necessary to display the longest row (based on components width). Having said this your `JLabel` fits the logo image width and nothing more and it looks like stick to left side. You have to tell the layout manager that it has to fill all available width when you instantiate it:

```
super.setLayout(new MigLayout("fillx"));
```

Or

```
LC layoutConstraints = new LC();
layoutConstraints.setFillX(true);
super.setLayout(new MigLayout(layoutConstraints);
```

Then, your component constraints will work as expexted.

---

#### Picture

Based on this code snippet:

```
MigLayout layout = new MigLayout("fillx, debug");
JPanel content = new JPanel(layout);

JLabel label = new JLabel("Warehouse");
label.setFont(label.getFont().deriveFont(Font.BOLD | Font.ITALIC, 18));

CC componentConstraints = new CC();
componentConstraints.alignX("center").spanX();
content.add(label, componentConstraints);
```

[image]

---

***Note:*** you can enable debug feature by doing this:

```
super.setLayout(new MigLayout("fillx, debug"));
```

Or

```
LC layoutConstraints = new LC();
layoutConstraints.setFillX(true);
layoutConstraints.setDebugMillis(500);
super.setLayout(new MigLayout(layoutConstraints);
```

Comment: I use super because i extend jpanel. The thing is i use boxlayout on my jframe with boxlayout.CENTER on the panel i.need the logo.centred, so i dont know the width of the component im using the miglayout on.

Comment: Ok but you would have to tell that in your question first. Without seeing your complete code (better a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) we can only guess. 1) Why BoxLayout in your JFrame? I'd use the default BoderLayout. 2) Why BoxLayout in a JPanel? If you have a more powerful layout manager such as MigLayout, why bothering to work with a very limited one, such as BoxLayout? @BenBeri

Comment: Well that fixed it, sometimes I need to also do "fill" in order to center it by x and y too, that's cool.

Comment: What does not work exactly? Could you please post a question with a working example reproducing the issue? @JPM