# Grow table larger than growx

Tags: java, swing, miglayout

I have configured my layout like that:

```
    panel.add(addButtons(), "wrap");    
    panel.add(showTable(), "growx, wrap");
```

So at first I am adding a button group and then I would like to grow my table as large as it can and then wrap the next component in the next "line".

However, my gui looks like that:

[image]

Here you clearly cannot see any values from the table. Therefore, how to grow the table so that each value can be seen?

I appreciate your answer!

Comment: did you tried to "fill" insteed of growX?

Comment: @Antoniossss When replacing `growx` with `fill`, I get: `Illegal Constraint: 'fill'`

Comment: Hopefully [this hint](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24977528/1795530) about using `fillx` will be useful. You can use it in combination with `growx` to make the row grow and be filled.

Comment: @Vivien override/set value for getPreferredScrollableSize for JTable, then this Dimension (used by JScrollPane) returns proper PreferredSize back to container, agree with TableColum.setPreferredWidth(500); for

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *Here you clearly cannot see any values from the table. Therefore, how to grow the table so that each value can be seen?*

As I've said in my comment, I don't think your problem is about columns (preferred | min | max) sizes but the default behavior of your layout manager: [MigLayout](http://www.miglayout.com/). As stated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24977528/1795530) by default rows in `MigLayout` doesn't **fill** all available width but just the necessary to display the longest row (based on components width). You can see this fact if you enable "debug" feature when you instantiate your layout:

```
MigLayout layout = new MigLayout("debug");
```

As I understand your question you need a combination of both `growx` and `fillx` constraint. The first one is a component constraint and the other one is a layout constraint.

That being said, pelase consider the following progression.

#### 1. Adding scroll pane *without* "growx" constraint

**Snippet**

```
MigLayout layout = new MigLayout("debug");
JPanel panel = new JPanel(layout);
panel.add(buttonsPanel, "wrap");
panel.add(scrollPane);
```

**Screenshot**

[image: Without growx constraint]

#### 2. Adding scroll pane *with* "growx" constraint

**Snippet**

```
MigLayout layout = new MigLayout("debug");
JPanel panel = new JPanel(layout);
panel.add(buttonsPanel, "wrap");
panel.add(scrollPane, "growx"); // Note "growx" here
```

**Screenshot**

[image: With growx constraint]

#### 3. Adding scroll pane *with* "growx" and "fillx" contraints

**Snippet**

```
MigLayout layout = new MigLayout("debug, fillx"); // Note "fillx" here
JPanel panel = new JPanel(layout);
panel.add(buttonsPanel, "wrap");
panel.add(scrollPane, "growx"); // Note "growx" here
```

**Screenshot**

[image: With growx and fillx constraints]

Answer (score 2):

You can use  `javax.swing.table.TableColumn;`

```
TableColumn custom_column = yourTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(1); // 1 means column 1 
custom_column.setPreferredWidth(500);
```

As you want to widen all columns you can use loop :

```
         TableColumn custom_column ;
         int numberOfColumns  = yourTable.getColumnModel().getColumnCount();

         for(int y= 0;y<numberOfColumns;y++){
            custom_column=table.getColumnModel().getColumn(y);
            custom_column.setMinWidth(500);
         }
```

Comment: Is it possible to specify this for all columns in the table model?

Comment: @vivien, as far as I know for default there isnt, but with the help of loop you can iterate each of your column indexes to put inside .getColumn(int columnPosition) as parameter. Then you can set preffered size for those columns.