# Miglayout grid constraints custom layout

Tags: java, swing, constraints, layout-manager, miglayout

i'm new here so go easy on me.
I've researched all the documentation on miglayout (which is pretty good btw) but I can't seem to properly display the grid that I want.

I need MigLayout() parameters to setup a grid as:

2 rows, being that the bottom row is split in half (or if you will: 1 top row adjacent to 2 bottom columns). 
The top row will display the search textfield with an adjancent button.
The bottom left column will display 3 buttons stacked on top of each other.
The bottom right column will display an image label.

Here's some code to start with:

```
//main window panel setup
            JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
            mainWindow.add(mainPanel);
            mainPanel.setLayout(new MigLayout(""));

            //components insertion into panel (using MigLayout constraints)
            mainPanel.add(searchText);
            mainPanel.add(searchBtn, "wrap");
            mainPanel.add(addBtn);
            mainPanel.add(logoImage, "spany 3 , wrap");
            mainPanel.add(randomBtn, "wrap");
            mainPanel.add(getFileBtn);
```

(could not upload image)

With this code, Notice that the logo is being kept below the searchButton (i think it does this due to the layout being default-set as a grid) but I want it to fit adjacent-right to the buttons and below the textfield/searchButton.

Comment: oh all ye programming geniuses please help

Comment: special shout out to mikael griev(?) for creating MigLayout

Comment: +1 for code snippet showing your effort, but next time please consider add a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) instead. This will make easier to test what have you tried.

Answer (score 8):

First off I would say you are pretty close and you only need to play with both columns number and constraints (plus some missing component constraints). This can be done when you instantiate your layout:

```
MigLayout layout = new MigLayout("debug, fillx", "[][grow][]");
```

Note `debug` and `fillx` are layout constraints intended to enable debug feature and fill whole width, respectively. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25531070/grow-table-larger-than-growx/25535913#25535913) for more details.

Now you can think you need two columns, but you actually need three columns in order to expand the middle one, while first and last columns continue occupying the minimum possible width. That's what `[][grow][]` constraints mean.

Please consider this snippet:

```
MigLayout layout = new MigLayout("debug, fillx", "[][grow][]");
JPanel content = new JPanel(layout);
// First row        
content.add(new JTextField(20), "spanx 2, growx"); // search text field
content.add(new JButton("Search"), "wrap");
// Second row
content.add(new JButton("Button # 1"), "growx");
content.add(new JLabel("Image here"), "span 2 3, grow, wrap"); // image label
content.add(new JButton("Button # 2"), "growx, wrap");
content.add(new JButton("Button # 3"), "growx, wrap");
```

This will produce something like this:

[image: Custom layout example]

Please note that on horizontal resizing both search text field and image label will occupy the maximum available width, while search button and button's stack will occupy just the minimum possible width.

Comment: You are welcome :) If this answer is good enough to you then pelase [accept it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). @noBrainer