# Resize table in miglayou

Tags: java, swing, layout, layout-manager, miglayout

I have created a MigLayout, which looks like that:

[image]

As you can see the table does not resize correctly.

I am creating my layout like that:

```
public JScrollPane createLayout() {
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new MigLayout("debug 400"));
    JScrollPane sp;

    JLabel lab = new JLabel(labelValue);
    lab.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 15));

    panel.add(lab, "wrap");
    panel.add(resultsTable(), "growx, wrap");
    panel.add(resultsButtons(), "wrap");

    //set table properties
    tableProperties(resultTable);
    updateResultsTable();

    sp = new JScrollPane(panel);
    sp.repaint();
    sp.validate();

    return sp;
}
```

My table is created like that:

```
private JPanel resultsTable() {
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new MigLayout(""));
    JScrollPane scrollTablePane;
    rtm = new ResultTableModel(resultList);
    resultTable = new JTable(rtm);
    scrollTablePane = new JScrollPane(resultTable);
    sorter = new TableRowSorter<TableModel>(resultTable.getModel());
    resultTable.setRowSorter(sorter);

    scrollTablePane.repaint();
    scrollTablePane.validate();

    //add to panel
    panel.add(scrollTablePane);
    panel.repaint();
    panel.validate();

    return panel;
}
```

Furthermore, I set the table properties in the following method:

```
public void tableProperties(JTable table) {
    table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_ALL_COLUMNS);
}
```

Any recommendations why my columns of my table do not stretch?

I appreciate your answer!

Comment: See this related Q&A: [Resize table larger than growx](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25535913/1795530).

Comment: I run into some missing identifiers in your code: resultsButtons(), resultTable, updateResultsTable(), rtm, class ResultTableModel [from NCSA, gSwing, DFKI?], resultList, and sorter. Do you use [MiG Layout 4.2](http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=com/miglayout/miglayout-swing/4.2/miglayout-swing-4.2.jar)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your table to be auto resizable try to use inside `createLayout` method the following constructor `JPanel panel = new JPanel(new MigLayout("debug 400,wrap 1","[grow,fill]","[grow,fill]"))` and inside `resultsTable` method the following constructor `JPanel panel = new JPanel(new MigLayout("","[grow,fill]","[grow,fill]"))`