# Making a scrollpane larger in MiGLayout

Tags: java, swing, layout, layout-manager, miglayout

I'm hacking together a UI, and I can't make a middle column larger and I can't figure out why.

[image]

No matter how much I adjust the size of the middle column, it always stays the same. I want it to be larger to the right and for the buttons on the right to be pushed away a bit.

I'm guessing this isn't enough information but I don't know what I could include.

Comment: *"I'm guessing this isn't enough information but I don't know what I could include."*  1) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example). 2) Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of the *intended* layout of the GUI at minimum size, and if resizable, with more width and height. 3) See also [How to create great screenshots?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/99734/155831)

Comment: Agree with @AndrewThompson. Perhaps the hints about `growx` and `fillx` contraints shown in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25535913/1795530) can help you to understand MigLayout contraints better and hopefully might lead you to solve your problem.